# Returning an adaptive card in a Teams messaging extension-should this work?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm experimenting with messaging extensions for MS Teams (using the .net SDK), and I'm running into a problem building a response to a query.  I have a handler that can handle the invoke with composeExtension/query, and it works fine if I return a HeroCard, but not an AdaptiveCard.  Here's my working HeroCard code:

```
        MessagingExtensionResult result = new MessagingExtensionResult
        {
            Type = "result",
            AttachmentLayout = "list",
            Attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment>(),
        };

        HeroCard h = new HeroCard()
        {
            Text = "Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya, you killed my father, prepare to die.",
            Tap = new CardAction()
            {
                Type = "messageBack",                   
                Text = "option1",
            },
        };
        result.Attachments.Add(new Attachment() { ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType, Content = h }.ToMessagingExtensionAttachment());
```

And here's the version I'm trying with an adaptive card:

```
        AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();

        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Hello",
            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.ExtraLarge
        });

        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveImage()
        {
            Url = new Uri("http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png")
        });

        result.Attachments.Add(new Attachment() { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = card }.ToMessagingExtensionAttachment());
```

The code to create the adaptive card is taken directly from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/authoring-cards/net).

The [documentation on messaging extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions/search-extensions) implies that adaptive cards should be supported in this scenario (with type application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive).  When I get the initialFetch result from the extension, and I return an AdaptiveCard (either alone or with a working HeroCard in the array), I get the "Something went wrong with this app." message in Teams.  Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Would this be for a v3 or v4 bot? The GitHub repo for this (github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams) states it is only for v3 at this time. There is no v4 offering yet. The doc link to the Nuget package also states it is only valid for Microsoft.Bot.Builder (>= 3.5.9 && < 4.0.0).

Comment: Good point, forgot to mention that.  V4 with the 4.0.0 beta nuget package.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Are you still needing help?

Comment: No, I never managed to get it working.  The answer I got on github was that adaptive cards aren't supported in previews though, so I suppose this is "not working as intended".  https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this off, I opened this as a bug on the github project, and it looks like the answer is that it's not supported at this time:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet/issues/15